# Using ImmutableJS in React component

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

There are some cases where react project needs immutableJS to speed up it's performance.
But it will screw up what react component code will be written as following code.
Instead of the native **dot** operator , we do have to use immutable instance method(**get,getIn,set,setIn**) ,which will bloat the code and lost the benfefit of the intellisense and static check from **IDE** or **Typescript**.

I know there's an alternative lib **seamless-immutable** which can save my life.

But are there other simle ways out there in terms of using **immutableJS** in **react component** in the way we write the native javascript plain object.

```js
/*Redux part is ommitted and assumed to be all converted to immutable  structure */

class Exam extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchHomeWorkList(); // ajax fetch data
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.loading || !this.props.homeWorkList ? (
      <Load />
    ) : (
      this.props.homeWorkList.map(homework => (
         <li>{homework.get("title")}</li>
          {homework.get("subHomeWorkList").map(homeWorkEntity => (
            <span>{homeWorkEntity.get("subTitle")}</span>
            <span>{homeWorkEntity.get("content")}</span>
          ))}
        
      ))
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  homeWorkList: state.getIn(["exam", "homeWorkList"]),
  loading: state.getIn(["exam", "loading"])
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Records but it requires a bit more work than maps:

#### With Maps

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const user = fromJS({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Snow",
});
```

#### With Records

```
import { Record } from 'immutable';

const userFactory = Record({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
});

const user = userFactory({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Snow",
});
```

To use Records you should define record factories for each type of the leaf node in your store. This is what `Record()` constructor is used for.

To create a record, you pass JSON object to the record factory. Record instance is similar to a `Map` but, amongst other things, it allows you to access its fields directly without calling `get()`

```
user.get('firstName') === user.firstName
```

Comment: I'd appreaciate it but it will still need the get,set,getIn methods to access it if the nested properties under one Immutable.Record is Immutable.map or Immutable.List too.

Comment: You can nest records with a little constructor tweaking. I'd only use maps for objects where you don't know all possible keys in advance, but this will also affect the way you access those objects in the components.  Lists are iterators, and they have `.map` too, so in most cases, their access mechanism will be the same as with arrays.